# Heat transfer FEM with nonlinear Cp

Tags: finite-element-method, heat-equation

I would like to solve a 3D heat transfer problem with nonlinear heat capacity Cp (Cp=1*T[t,x,y,z]). My problem is very simple: a slab with the bottom surface insulated and the other five surfaces subjected convection BCs. I followed this document to form my code. https://reference.wolfram.com/language/PDEModels/tutorial/HeatTransfer/HeatTransfer.html

The code can run successfully with constant Cp or even nonlinear thermal conductivity (e.g., k=0.05 T[t,x,y,z]. However, it does not want to calculate for the nonlinear Cp case. Can someone help me?

The code is:

```
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"]
ClearAll[HeatTransferModel]
HeatTransferModel[T_, X_List, k_, \[Rho]_, Cp_, Velocity_, Source_] :=
Module[{V, Q, a = k},
V = If[Velocity === "NoFlow", 
0, \[Rho]*Cp*Velocity.Inactive[Grad][T, X]];
Q = If[Source === "NoSource", 0, Source];
If[ FreeQ[a, _?VectorQ], a = a*IdentityMatrix[Length[X]]];
If[ VectorQ[a], a = DiagonalMatrix[a]];
(* Note the - sign in the operator *)
a = PiecewiseExpand[Piecewise[{{-a, True}}]];
Inactive[Div][a.Inactive[Grad][T, X], X] + V - Q]

TimeHeatTransferModel[T_, TimeVar_, X_List, k_, \[Rho]_, Cp_, 
Velocity_, Source_] := \[Rho]*Cp*D[T, {TimeVar, 1}] + 
HeatTransferModel[T, X, k, \[Rho], Cp, Velocity, Source]

Subscript[\[Rho], ac] = 2000;
Subscript[k, ac] = 2;
Subscript[Cp, ac] = 1*T[t, x, y, z];

a = 0.3;
d = 0.05;
reg = Cuboid[{-a/2, -a/2, -d/2}, {a/2, a/2, d/2}];
mesh = ToElementMesh[reg, MaxCellMeasure -> 5*10^-6];
mesh["Wireframe"]

Ta = 60 + 273
h = 300
q = -h*(T[t, x, y, z] - Ta);
IC = {T[0, x, y, z] == 20 + 273};
Subscript[\[CapitalGamma], top] = NeumannValue[q, z == d/2];
Subscript[\[CapitalGamma], side1] = NeumannValue[q, x == a/2];
Subscript[\[CapitalGamma], side2] = NeumannValue[q, x == -a/2];
Subscript[\[CapitalGamma], side3] = NeumannValue[q, y == a/2];
Subscript[\[CapitalGamma], side4] = NeumannValue[q, y == -a/2];
Subscript[\[CapitalGamma], bottom] = NeumannValue[0, z == -d/2];

pde = {TimeHeatTransferModel[T[t, x, y, z], t, {x, y, z}, Subscript[k,
  ac], Subscript[\[Rho], ac], Subscript[Cp, ac], "NoFlow", 
 "NoSource"] == 
Subscript[\[CapitalGamma], top] + Subscript[\[CapitalGamma], 
 side1] + Subscript[\[CapitalGamma], side2] + 
 Subscript[\[CapitalGamma], side3] + Subscript[\[CapitalGamma], 
 side4] + Subscript[\[CapitalGamma], bottom], IC};

 tend = 10000;
 Tfun = NDSolveValue[pde, T, {t, 0, tend}, {x, y, z} \[Element] mesh];
 Tfun[tend, 0, 0, 0]
```

Comment: When I run this in 12.1 I get convergence errors. What do you see?

Comment: @user21 My error reads: NDSolveValue::ndcf: Repeated convergence test failure at t == 0.000025`; unable to continue.

Comment: It's hard to say if this convergence error is because the setup is not correct or because `NDSolve` can currently not handle this. There is, however, an example of a nonlinear Cp in the [FEM Programming tutorial](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/FEMDocumentation/tutorial/FiniteElementProgramming.html) - in the section [Transient PDEs with Nonlinear Transient Coefficients](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/FEMDocumentation/tutorial/FiniteElementProgramming.html#675160945) - perhaps you can start with a 1D model in NDSolve and compare that to the tutorial example?

Comment: @user21 Thank you for the reference. I will take a look. It is interesting to see that a nonlinear k runs successfully but a nonlinear Cp does not work.

Comment: OK, I have tried this example in the development version (a future version not yet available - probably version 12.2) and there it runs without errors and `Tfun[tend, 0, 0, 0]` returns `333`. To get something to work in 12.1 you'd have make use of the example from the FEM programming tutorial I linked above. The code should be dimension agnostic; give it a shot. Let me know if it works if you do.

Comment: @user21 Yes, the method works. I compared with the FEM for the constant Cp, and the results are same. However, there is an error in the document of the section "Transient PDEs with Nonlinear Transient Coefficients". Find the "Set up nonlinear parameters". The input[5] Cp[T_] equation is actually not specific heat Cp[T_], it is actually density*Cp[T_], or the volumetric heat capacity. When you look at the code, you don't see a density term in the entire calculation, because it is lumped into the Cp[T_] term. When I corrected the term, the code worked the same as the FEM.

Comment: Thanks. Are you saying it would be clearer in the example to write `"DampingCoefficients" -> {{rho*Cp[T[t, x]]}}` in stead of `"DampingCoefficients" -> {{Cp[T[t, x]]}}` where the` Cp` has the rho (density) absorbed?

Comment: @user21 Yes. And In[5]: Cp[T_] := \[Theta][T]*2*10^6 + (1 - \[Theta][T])*4*10^6;This expression of Cp[T_] has the rho absorbed. The value of Cp[T_] is usually several hundreds in J/(kgK). The value of this expression is 10^6. Clearly, it has rho absorbed. This expression is Cv (J/(m^3 K)).

Comment: OK, done, a future version will have this improvement for the code/documentation. Thanks.