# Which methods are available for NDEigensystem?

Tags: differential-equations, finite-element-method, implementation-details, eigenvalues

I am trying to find out what methods/options are available for `NDEigensystem` and descriptions of their use. Perusing the help, online Q&As, Mathematica's in-line autofill, etc., I've found a few, but it's unclear what they do. For example, what is the a difference between `Method -> {"PDEDiscretization" -> {"FiniteElement", "MeshOptions" -> {"MaxCellMeasure" -> Automatic}}}` and `Method -> {"SpatialDiscretization" -> {"FiniteElement", {"MeshOptions" -> {MaxCellMeasure -> Automatic}}}}`.
To confuse things further, some Methods seem have additional options (e.g., `"Eigensystem"`).

Is there a way to uncover all the available `Method`s available to NDEigensystem, including a description and their options?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is a tutorial called [NDSolve Options for Finite Elements](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/FEMDocumentation/tutorial/FiniteElementOptions.html) that is the main tutorial for Finite Element related options. It names all FEM options (but one) and either gives examples and explanations for them or links to the respective location in the documentation where you can find more information.

Concerning `NDEigensystem` specifically all options are documented on the ref page of `NDEigensystem`. Sub-options to functions called from `NDEigensystem` like `Eigensystem` are documented in their respective reference pages.

Concerning your specific questions: Method -> "PDEDiscretization" and Method -> "SpatialDiscretization" they are the same in the context of `NDEigensystem`. The initially available options was "SpatialDiscretization" but we added "PDEDiscretization"->FEM because for a casual user it may not be obvious that `NDEigensystem` assembles a time dependent problem and it was confusing to customers that they would need to specify a "SpatialDiscretization" which is in contrast to the MethodOfLines option for time dependent PDEs.

The pattern for FEM sub options is mostly this: `{"SubfunctionSpecification", "SubfunctionOptions"..}`. I can make that clearer in the above mentioned tutorial. The "SubfunctionSpecification" is either a string function name or a string function name or a string function name with  "Options" appended to the name, like "LinearSolveOptions".

The methods available for NDEigensystem are, Direct, Arnoldi and FEAST. The direct eigen sovler is very slow and only usable for very small problems. It is the most stable solver, however. The Arnoldi is the default and an iterative solver that can handle large equation system as generated by NDEigensystem. The FEAST solver should be used if one is interested in a band of eigenvalues.

Let me take opportunity to say the following: If anyone has suggestions for improving the FEM documentation by all means let me know. I take these suggestions very serious and I pride myself that FEM in the language is one of the best documented subsystems. The most convenient suggestions for me are something like: "This sentence/paragraph/etc XXXX is hard to understand. If you (that is I) where to change it to YYYY and add the following example code [codeZZZ] that would go a long way" The it's easy for me to make the adjustment [like done a few days ago here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/224050/heat-transfer-fem-with-nonlinear-cp).

Comment: Honestly this is a big reason I think I may end up writing a micromagnetics fem solver for Mathematica, for fun, of course ;)

Comment: @CATrevillian, that would be very exiting! By all means do. This would be a nice addition to the [FEMAddOns](https://github.com/WolframResearch/FEMAddOns).

Comment: @user21 Thanks for the helpful response. I tried RTFM, but clearly I missed stuff. What is the best way to contact you?

Comment: @EliLansey, ideally you'd ask questions here such that other people can benefit from them. It is also fine to ping me in comments. I may not always be able to respond immediately.

Comment: @user21 A section that I find particular confusing is the Possible Issues discussion on the “temporal description”. I don’t understand how to convert a PDE to the temporal description. From the single example there, it looks like you just add an argument t, and wrap everything in a D[#, {t,1}]. I tried that, as well, and got notice that the Arnoldi algorithm wasn’t converging, but I likely did something wrong.

Comment: @user21 I also couldn’t find any info in the NDEigensystem docs where all the "Eigensystem" solution options are listed (in the examples there was Arnoldi, Direct, FEAST – is that all?), or why one should use one kind of solver vs another.
The relationship between NDEigensystem and the various other ND* and matrix Eigensystem options isn’t totally clear, either.

Comment: @EliLansey, thank you for your suggestions I added further explanations to the mentioned sections to clarify the points raised by you. These will be available in the 12.2 release. I also send you a private message with more details on the changes. See updates to my answer.